# Rescale not working Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, computer-vision

I'm trying to build and train a version of SegNet from [here](https://github.com/alexgkendall/SegNet-Tutorial/blob/master/Example_Models/bayesian_segnet_camvid.prototxt) in Keras and get a ValueError when training. My training data is of the form:

RGB images:

```
train.shape
```

(382,200,200,3)

Masks with one-hot labels for 3 region classes:

```
label.shape
```

(382,200,200,3)

The model is as follows:

```
inshape=(200, 200, 3)
classes=3

# c.f. https://github.com/alexgkendall/SegNet-Tutorial/blob/master/Example_Models/bayesian_segnet_camvid.prototxt
img_input = Input(shape=inshape)
x = img_input
# Encoder
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
print(x.shape)
#x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
print(x.shape)

x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
print(x.shape)
#x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
print(x.shape)

x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
print(x.shape)
#x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
print(x.shape)

x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
print(x.shape)
#x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)

# Decoder
x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
print(x.shape)
#x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)

x = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(x)
print(x.shape)
x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
print(x.shape)
#x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)

x = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(x)
print(x.shape)
x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
print(x.shape)
#x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)

x = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(x)
print(x.shape)
x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
print(x.shape)
#x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)

x = Convolution2D(classes, (1,1), padding="valid")(x)
print(x.shape)


#x = Dense(classes,activation='softmax')(x)

x = Reshape((inshape[0]*inshape[1],classes), input_shape = (200,200,3))(x)
#x = x.reshape((-1,40000,3))
print(x.shape)
x = Activation("softmax")(x)

model = Model(img_input, x)
```

The print statements give:

```
(?, 200, 200, 64)
(?, 100, 100, 64)
(?, 100, 100, 128)
(?, 50, 50, 128)
(?, 50, 50, 256)
(?, 25, 25, 256)
(?, 25, 25, 512)
(?, 25, 25, 512)
(?, 50, 50, 512)
(?, 50, 50, 256)
(?, 100, 100, 256)
(?, 100, 100, 128)
(?, 200, 200, 128)
(?, 200, 200, 128)
(?, 200, 200, 3)
(?, 40000, 3)
```

Compiling with:

```
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adadelta', metrics=["accuracy"])
```

runs fine.
Fitting with:

```
model.fit(train,label,epochs = 1)
```

Gives the following error:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-fd1c2ff82d80> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(train,label,epochs = 1)

c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1628             sample_weight=sample_weight,
   1629             class_weight=class_weight,
-> 1630             batch_size=batch_size)
   1631         # Prepare validation data.
   1632         do_validation = False

c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
   1478                                     output_shapes,
   1479                                     check_batch_axis=False,
-> 1480                                     exception_prefix='target')
   1481         sample_weights = _standardize_sample_weights(sample_weight,
   1482                                                      self._feed_output_names)

c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    111                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    112                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 113                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    114                 if not check_batch_axis:
    115                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_60 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (383, 200, 200, 3)
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: you have 382 examples and 3 classes so, your one hot matrix should be of shape (382,3)

Comment: @user8190410 the labels are in the form of a mask as this is an image segmentation task. Therefore, each pixel in the 200x200 image, across the 382 images has a one-hot label

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

I wasn't reshaping the masks before passing them in. At the training stage the network output is compared to the mask. After reshaping, the network output was indeed `(-1,40000,3)` but the mask was was not reshaped to match this.

Reshaping the mask to the correct output fixes the problem.